# Repeatedly unpickling files causing memory leak

Tags: python, memory-leaks, pickle

I'm working with large pickled data files, and found that if I repeatedly import the same files into the same variables, my memory usage increases.  The files aren't anything special.  Just objects that contain several huge multidimensional lists.

Here are the data import methods:

```
def import_sim_data(self):
    gbts = self.import_gbt_data()
    eq = self.import_eq_data()
    ss = self.import_ss_data()
    ngeo = self.import_near_geo_data()
    lunar_phase = self.import_lunar_phase_data()
    return gbts, eq, ss, ngeo, lunar_phase

@staticmethod
def import_gbt_data():
    with open("gbt_data.res", "rb") as f:
        gbts = pickle.load(f)
    return gbts

@staticmethod
def import_eq_data():
    with open("eq_data.res", "rb") as f:
        eq = pickle.load(f)
    return eq

@staticmethod
def import_ss_data():
    with open("ss_data.res", "rb") as f:
        ss = pickle.load(f)
    return ss

@staticmethod
def import_near_geo_data():
    with open("near_geo_data.res", "rb") as f:
        ngeo = pickle.load(f)
    return ngeo

@staticmethod
def import_lunar_phase_data():
    with open("moon_phase.res", "rb") as f:
        lunar_phase = pickle.load(f)
    return lunar_phase
```

If I run a, b, c, d, e = problem.import_sim_data() five times in a row, each time the memory usage for my python process increases dramatically and unpredictably.  I went from 6585MB used on the first import to 7986MB, to 8581MB, to 9872MB, to 10432MB.  What would cause this kind of behavior?  I can import a large text file hundreds of times in a row without any problems at all.

(BTW, this isn't how the code is normally used, but I'm troubleshooting a memory leak in an MPI program, and stumbled on this phenomenon.)

Comment: I had a problem with a numpy 1.16 pickling memory leak on arrays. I downgraded to 1.15 to solve it. I think there is an open issue [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12793).